# jointJS javascript logic circuit example

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, jointjs

I am trying to understand how jointJS works, specifically this example [logic circuit simulation](http://www.jointjs.com/demos/logic)
There are few parts which I am not quite sure what is happening.

> _.invoke(graph.getLinks(), 'set', 'signal', 0);

Looking at the invoke function, 'set' and 'signal' should be the methodNames, but how can we use two methods at the same time?

> graph.on('change:signal', function(wire, signal)

Translating this would be.. when the signal is changed, function(wire,signal) is run. As i'm quite new with Javascript, I don't know what is being passed (wire, signal) into this function and how it is obtained?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For your first question `_.invoke(graph.getLinks(), 'set', 'signal', 0);`

It's using the underscore.js function of invoke.  It will take a list (your graph.getLinks() list) and invoke a method on each item in that list.  The arguments are taken after the function.  So in this case, you're getting all of the links on the graph, and then setting the signal to 0 for each one of them.

For your second command `graph.on('change:signal', function(wire, signal)`

From what i've worked with on joint, this is a backbone.js event.  Where the function passes in for the change event.  http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog  Usually it's one of two items there in that list.  The change event, or the change:attribute event.  So this looks like a change:signal which is an attribute, so it's probably (model, view, options) is what it's passing in.  If you're really curious of the data available, use chrome and set a breakpoint to inspect the variables being passed in.

Hope that helps.

For reference :

- http://underscorejs.org/
- http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: I see. Thanks! Didn't know that it uses backbone.js as well. Still new to all these things